# How to do a postgres Select statement which contains round brackets in a batch?

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, for-loop, select, brackets

I am trying to do a select in to a postgres DB via batch file.
The postgres DB offers a command line interface (psql) where you can pipe in DB commands which is here done in for loop. Look at how pg_cmd is stiched together. The select pd_SelCmd is echoed to pg_SelCall.
In the for statement the command is executed but since the select contains round brackets, they cause a miss interpretation and an error: 
"FROM" cant be processed syntactically at this point.

**How can the round brackets be kind of escaped to get the request to work?**

The expected response from DB looks like:

```
          max
-------------------------
2016-12-29 09:40:09.842
(1 Line)
```

The batch used so far was this

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "PgRootPath=C:\Program Files\PostgreSql\9.5.5-1\bin"
Call :GetDoneTime 56665454 DONE_TIME
echo = DONE_TIME=!DONE_TIME!
Goto :EOF

:GetDoneTime
set "ERRORLEVEL="
set "MC_UID=%~1"
set "ReturnDoneTimeValueRef=%~2"
set "DataVal=NULL"
set "PGPASSWORD=frontenduser"
set "PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8"

set pd_SelCmd=SELECT max(t.endDate) FROM Ticket t JOIN Device d on t.device_id = d.id WHERE t.state in ('APPROVED','IN_PROGRESS', 'IN_ACTIVITY') AND d.uid='!MC_UID!';
set pg_SelCall="!PgRootPath!\psql" -U frontenduser -h localhost -d ppsdb
REM if call to psql produces an fatal error, the error number will be passed to for loop on third parameter in third line
set pg_cmd="echo !pd_SelCmd! | !pg_SelCall! || echo/ & echo/ & call echo NULL NULL %%^^^errorlevel%%"
set "pg_cmd=!pg_cmd:)=^)!"

REM Execute PG command. Resulting DataValue obtained from third row
REM Check for errors of call
for /f "skip=2 tokens=1,2,3" %%i in ('!pg_cmd!') do (       
    REM Get value in first and second parameter from split - which is from third row
    set "DataVal=%%i %%j"
    REM If error happend, report it. Error code is obtained in 3rd parameter.
    if "!DataVal!"=="NULL NULL" (
        echo ## Postgres DB operation failed with ERROR: %%~k
        set "DataVal=NULL"
    ) else (
        REM Check if result is not valid
        if "!DataVal:~0,1!"=="(" set "DataVal=NULL"
    )
    goto GotDoneTime
)
:GotDoneTime
    if not '!ReturnDoneTimeValueRef!'=='' set "!ReturnDoneTimeValueRef!=!DataVal!"
    if "!DataVal!"=="NULL" exit /b 1
    exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few errors here. Unfortunately, I don't know postgresql, nor do I have the requisite database, so I can't test it, but here goes...

First, labels are not allowed in a code-block (parenthesised series of statements) and `::` is a broken label. Within a code block, `rem` should be used for remarks.

Next, replacing your `'!pg_cmd!` in the `for` loop with `type q41353737.txt` (where `q41353737.txt` is a file containing the expected data output from the command you posted) then `dataval` is set to `09:40:09.842` **BUT** since there is a fourth line in the file, the next line will also be processed and `dataval` will be set to `Line)`.

To overcome this, you could simply change this to

```
   rem If error happened, report it. Error code is obtained in 3rd parameter.
   if not '%%~k'=='' echo ## Postgres DB operation failed with ERROR: %%~k
   rem If operation succeeded, get value in second parameter from split - which is from second data column
   if '%%~k'=='' SET DataVal=%%~j
goto done
)
:done
```

so that only the third line is processed and then the `for` loop is unceremoniously terminated.

Next problem is the problem of which you complain. The `)` is terminating the `for ... (`, so you need to tell `cmd` that that particular `)` is *part of the command to be executed*, not of the `for`, so you need to escape it with a caret (`(` becomes `^)`)

The easiest way is probably, just before the `for` to add a line

```
set "pg_cmd=!pg_cmd:)=^)!"
```

which should appropriately prefix all `)` in the command withh the requisite caret.

I suspect you'll also have trouble with the other problem characters so a similar process applied to `|` will probably be required, ie.

```
set "pg_cmd=!pg_cmd:|=^|!"
```

Which is where I have to leave it, since I've no way of correctly executing the command itself.

Comment: I have updated the code.
More details of the double colon problem can be red here http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php.
Although I haven't found problems with it in all Windows versions >=7 in future I will use REM to be on the save side.
I have removed some unnecessary brackets and added the line to replace `)` by `^)` and now it works.
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Since this little example contains several complex operations, I have added a few comments and improved error handling. For similar selects it can be easily adjusted.